# Zachman Framework

Tags: enterprise-architect

Need pointers to understanding Zachman framework for Enterprise Architecture with some reference implementation, case studies

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Zachman is not "Open Source", so the best way to understand it, is to book a training.

Nevertheless, a good starting point is Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zachman_Framework